# How to refresh value in angular html binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this html

```
<div ng-bind-html="safeHtml"></div>
<button ng-click="refresh()">refresh</button>
```

how refresh function should look like so it refresh the value.

Comment: `safeHtml` should already be two way bound, so there is no need to "refresh" it. Either that or you need to use `$scope.$watch`

Comment: @CallumLinington two way binding only update when I change safeHtml and I want to refresh it without chaning the content.

Comment: What does refresh do though? Dos it call an api, because otherwise it is redundant in a two way bind because the dirty checker will notice that the value has change and update all bindings.

Comment: If I have javascript that generate a graph I wan to rerender it. also I want to refresh the image (but this probably will require to modify html and add timestamp at the end).

Comment: I know some graph libraries are reactive to data set changes, maybe it's worth seeing if your chosen one has

Comment: How about using $scope.$apply() ?

Answer (score 1):

@jcubic it will automatically change when you use in a object(data.safeHtml). like -

```
<div ng-bind-html="data.safeHtml"></div>
<button ng-click="refresh()">refresh</button>
```

Comment: What you want to change exactly?

Comment: I just want to rerender the html because javascript may use global counter and display it on the page or I can have image that's changed on disk. Maybe other things as well.

Comment: You can use $scope.$apply() function.